# Random effects structure for nested, repeated measures in clmm?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, likert, nested-data

I'm trying to code a clmm model in R to analyze 1-5 Likert data.  Respondents in different cities were asked to take a survey twice: once before a treatment, then again afterwards (Treatment).  The model aims to assess whether and how the treatment interacts with demographic factors, namely respondent age (Age) and socioeconomic status (SES).  Thus, I believe I need a random effects structure that will accommodate both the nested nature of subjects (City), and the repeated measures (Subject).  I'm thinking my model should look something along the lines of: `clmm(Likert~Treatment*Age+Treatment*SES+(1|City/Subject)`, but I'm largely self-taught when it comes to mixed effects models and often struggle with defining random effects.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The proposed model is:

```
clmm(Likert ~ Treatment*Age + Treatment*SES + (1|City/Subject)
```

This model will fit fixed effects for:

- `Treatment`
- `Age`
- `SES`
- the two way interaction between `Treatment` and `Age`
- the two way interaction between `Treatment` and `SES`
- random intercepts for `City`
- random intercepts for `Subject` varying within `City` (ie `Subject` is nested within `City`.

Based on the description in the post, this seems like a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.